# aws athena - Create table by an array of json object

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, aws-glue

Can I get help in creating a table on AWS Athena. 
For a sample example of data :

```
[{"lts": 150}]
```

AWS Glue generate the schema as :

```
 array (array<struct<lts:int>>)
```

When I try to use the created table by AWS Glue to preview the table, I had this error:

```
HIVE_BAD_DATA: Error parsing field value for field 0: org.openx.data.jsonserde.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.openx.data.jsonserde.json.JSONArray
```

The message error is clear, but I can't find the source of the problem!

Comment: Why do you write `arrat(array<struct<lts:int>>)`? You don't mean a nested array, do you?

Comment: It was generated by AWS Glue crawler (json)!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hive running under AWS Athena is using [Hive-JSON-Serde](https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde/blob/develop/README.md) to serialize/deserialize JSON. For some reason, they don't support just any standard JSON. They ask for one record per line, without an array. In their words:

The following example will work.

```
{ "key" : 10 }
{ "key" : 20 }
```

But this won't:

```
{
  "key" : 20,
}
```

Nor this:

```
[{"key" : 20}]
```

Answer (score 4):

You should create a JSON classifier to convert array into list of object instead of a single array object. Use JSON path `$[*]` in your classifier and then set up crawler to use it:

- Edit crawler
- Expand 'Description and classifiers'
- Click 'Add' on the left pane to associate you classifier with crawler

After that remove previously created table and re-run the crawler. It will create a table with proper scheme but I think Athena will still be complaining when you will try to query it. However, now you can read from that table using Glue ETL job and process single record object instead of array-objects

Comment: This is correct, if you don't want to put objects in individual files, or separate lines. I found that I had to create a new crawler after creating the custom classifier, otherwise Glue would continue to classify as an array. Just another Glue bug I guess. Further docs here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/custom-classifier.html#custom-classifier-json

Comment: I also have found this the case.  It seems strange that this AWS-recommended classifier would cause Athena queries to break.

Answer (score 3):

This json - `[{"lts": 150}]` would work like a charm with below query:-

```
select n.lts from table_name
cross join UNNEST(table_name.array) as t (n)
```

The output would be as below:-
[image]

But I have faced a challenge with json like - `[{"lts": 150},{"lts": 250},{"lts": 350}]`. 
Even if there are 3 elements in the JSON, the query is returning only the first element. This may be because of the limitation listed by @artikas.
Definitely, we can change the json like below to make it work:-

```
{"lts": 150}
{"lts": 250}
{"lts": 350}
```

Please post if anyone is having a better solution to it.

Comment: Ran into the same issue where it only returns the first element when stored in an array.